# Is it possible to travel on river/canal from Bruges, Belgium to some point on the Rhine?

Tags: germany, netherlands, belgium, rivers, bruges

I want to take a canal/river trip that starts in Bruges (Belgium) and ends in the south of Germany. I cannot find the necessary information to tell me whether the river canal system in Bruges connects the system in Holland or Germany to get to the Rhine.

Can someone tell me if there is a line of connections to make such a trip possible?

Comment: Do you have your own boat or are you looking for public transport companies that would offer routes on all segments?

Comment: @gerrit, either would suite. Either option would appeal. If only one option exists I will take it or choose later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the following map (Source: http://www.yachtchartersneek.nl/waterkaart_Belgie_vaarwegen.htm)
[image]

The map is from a charter company, which have suggested routes on their website. One mentions a connection from [Bruges to Ghent](http://www.yachtchartersneek.nl/content/routes/midweek_bootje_varen_brugge.htm).
[image]

From Ghent on there a multiple possibilities.

Answer (score 6):

According to [Eurocanals](http://www.eurocanals.com/Waterways/europecountries.html) site, the answer is yes. One possible route is: Brugge - Gent - Antwerpen - Dordrecht - Nijmegen - Düsseldorf. From there you can even join the Danube River and the Black Sea.

Answer (score 1):

UNECE has a very good map of European waterways available here: https://unece.org/DAM/trans/main/sc3/AGN_map_2018.pdf

Here you can see that there are quite a few options. The route north to the Netherlands has already been mentioned, but you can also go south to France, and then across to the Rhine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from Brugge you can follow the Boudewijnkanaal to Zeebrugge, then turn North to where the Merwede and Rhine reach the North Sea.

Granted, this is not *exclusively* a canal/river trip, so your boat needs to be seaworthy.

Comment: It is also possible to go inland and use canals and sometimes rivers.